# all values are displayed except image when back clicked in php html

Tags: javascript, html

```
<input type='submit' onclick="history.go(-1)" />
```

By using this all the values in the fields are displaying , but the images are not.

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should check if cache is disabled in your browser - or your img is not being.

it should work and you should see the images.

maybe a cache disable mechanism is on.